# Select Statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to find all cars from the city of denver whose license plate begins with the letters 'ATV'.

My Select statement
is

```
Select * from coloradodmv where licenseplate = 'ATV'
```

I can't find any records. Can you help me?

Comment: Take a look at [LIKE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator. `SELECT * FROM coloradodmv WHERE licenseplate LIKE 'ATV%'`

Comment: select * from #plates where plateNo like 'ATV%'

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from coloradodmv where licenseplate LIKE 'ATV%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using

```
Select *
From coloradodmv
Where licenseplate 
Like 'ATV%';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, hudson1995.  I suspect you may need to include a placeholder variable?  Also, you may want to provide attribution to the comment from @rbock

Answer (score 0):

It has been answered already, but just to clarify how this works:

```
create table #plates (plateNo nvarchar(10))

insert into #plates 
values ('ATV1234'),
    ('BGZ1234'),
    ('ATV12345'),
    ('ATV123')

-- % represents 0 or more chars
select * from #plates where plateNo like 'ATV%'
--result
plateNo
ATV1234
ATV12345
ATV123

-- _ represents 1 char, __ respresents 2 chards and so on
select * from #plates where plateNo like 'ATV____'
--result
plateNo
ATV1234
```

IMPORTANT: with `"%"` and `"_"` you must use `LIKE` , you cannot use `=`
Example:

```
select * from #plates where plateNo = 'ATV%'
```

-- no result returned !